# Raise Column as Power in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': np.random.randn(6),
'b': np.random.randn(6),
})
```

I want to create another column, where

```
df['newCol] = 1/(1 + x) ^ df['a']
```

where `x = 0.15`

Could someone please tell me how to do it?

When I was trying to run the above code to get `newCol`, I'm getting the following error.

`TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]`

Thanks!

Comment: ``(1 / 1.15) ** df.a`` ?

Comment: Are you expecting the power to be the value in column `a`? can you provide an example of what you are expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html):

```
x = 0.15
df['newCol'] = np.power(1/(1 + x), df['a'])
```

Or like mentioned @sammywemmy in comments use `**` for power:

```
df['newCol'] = (1 / 1 + x) ** df.a

print (df)
          a         b    newCol
0  0.026375 -0.711352  0.996321
1  0.140704 -0.428927  0.980527
2  0.889247 -0.316721  0.883130
3  0.270489  1.826090  0.962902
4  0.832062 -1.021876  0.890216
5 -0.314291  2.014869  1.044905
```

Comment: @jezzael, you are way too fast to respond. I was half way thru the answer when I saw your post. +1 for speed.

Comment: @JoeFerndz - thanks, btw, I have same name like you ;)

Comment: @jezrael, yes, I decoded your dataframe a while back :)